# How can I filter array of <Any> by its type -Kotlin?

Tags: algorithm, kotlin

I have an array
`arrayOf<Any>("Apple",46,"287",574,"Peach","3","69",78,"Grape","423")` and I need to sort it: firstly numbers suppose to go like `"3",46,"69"...` and then words by alphabet... So I am trying first to divide them on separate arrays by type and then some manipulation. Do you have advice of how to solve this problem?

Comment: Does string numbers should be treated as strings or parsed and counted as Integers?

Comment: they suppose to be stay as strings. So as I showed it must be `"3",46,"69"` and NOT like `3,46,69`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a concise<sup>*</sup> approach:

```
val a = arrayOf<Any>("Apple", 46, "287", 574, "Peach", "3", "69", 78, "Grape", "423")

val (numbers, nonNumbers) = a.partition{ it.toString().toIntOrNull() != null }
val result = (numbers.sortedBy{ it.toString().toInt() }
            + nonNumbers.sortedBy{ it.toString() })

println(result) // [3, 46, 69, 78, 287, 423, 574, Apple, Grape, Peach]
```

This uses [`partition()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/partition.html) to split the array into two lists: one holding all the numbers, and one holding the rest. (To handle all possible types, it calls [`toString()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to-string.html), and then determines whether that string would be a valid integer.)

Then it sorts the first sublist (holding numbers) according to their integer value, and the second sublist lexicographically; finally, it uses [`+`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus.html) to join the sorted sublists into one.

This will work for elements of all possible types, not just String and Int. (However, although it's not clear from the output, the result preserves the original types; the string and integer conversions are only done temporarily for the purposes of sorting.)

Note that it produces a list, not an array. (It will also operate on a list or other collection.) Lists are much better supported in the standard library, can be resized, have a decent `toString()` implementation, come in mutable and immutable versions, have countless implementations with different characteristics, work better with generics, and several other advantages. Arrays are mainly for interoperability with old code, and a few specific uses (varargs, low-level implementation, and the `main()` method); for everything else, lists are much preferable.

(However, if you really *need* an array result, you can call `result.toTypedArray()`.)

---

<sup>*</sup> While it's fun to puzzle out the shortest solution, that doesn't *necessarily* make it the best…

In practice, the best code is clear, simple, easy to read and maintain; conciseness can help that, or it can go too far, and this answer might go *slightly* too far. (In fact, I've tweaked it since first posted, naming the sublists in the hope of making it a little more readable.)

This is also less efficient than some other answers, as it creates lots of temporary objects (four lists and many strings). In many cases, that may not matter — but it's worth being aware of.

In any event, it's always worth being aware of alternatives, and so I hope this is instructive!

Answer (score 1):

You can try my solution

```kotlin
val a = arrayOf<Any>("Apple",46,"287",574,"Peach","3","69",78,"Grape","423")
val numbers = mutableListOf<Any>()
val strings = mutableListOf<String>()

for(e in a){
    if(e is Int) numbers.add(e)
    if(e is String){
        if(e.toIntOrNull() == null){
            strings.add(e)
        } else {
            numbers.add(e)
        }
    }
}
   
val result = numbers.also { value -> value.sortBy{it.toString().toInt()} } + strings.sorted()
   
println(result) // [3, 46, 69, 78, 287, 423, 574, Apple, Grape, Peach]
```

Comment: The only problem here is if you have an `Int` like `46` that also has a matching `String` version `"46"`, that `stringNumber.find` call will succeed for both of them, and you'll end up with two `String` versions. You probably want to use `sortedBy` instead, so you can convert them to `Int`s inside the comparison function, and store them as their original type

Comment: @cactustictacs you are right, edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the array using a custom comparator:

```
fun main() {
    println(
        arrayOf<Any>("Apple",46,"287",574,"Peach","3","69",78,"Grape","423")
            .sortedWith(
                compareBy<Any> {
                    it is String && it.toLongOrNull() == null
                } then compareBy {
                    when {
                        it is Number -> it.toLong()
                        it is String && it.toLongOrNull() != null -> it.toLong()
                        else -> it.toString()
                    }
                }
            )
    )
}
```

Output: `[3, 46, 69, 78, 287, 423, 574, Apple, Grape, Peach]`

Comment: This answer does not sort the numbers, nor the non-numbers, as required by the question.

Comment: @gidds you're right, thanks. Corrected. Your answer looks better though.

Comment: Sorry if my comment seemed a little harsh :-) This answers the question perfectly now. (And it's shorter than mine, if you include all the explanation I had to give!) It's always worth seeing alternatives — I hadn't thought of combining comparators like that. In some ways, this is cleaner, as it only does a single sort, and no other list manipulation. Fewer temporary objects, too.

Comment: (One interesting difference between our answers is in how they handle objects that are neither String nor Number but whose toString looks like an integer: mine sorts them with the numbers, yours with the rest. I _think_ I prefer mine, but it's not at all obvious which is better.)

Comment: @gidds thanks for your thoughts. I also think I prefer your method of handling non-string non-numbers, but this gives an alternative approach so the OP can choose depending on what should be done with such data.

Answer (score 0):

So just had to make some manipulation

```
val onlyNumbers = a.filterIsInstance<Int>()
val allStrings = a.filterIsInstance<String>().sorted()
val onlyStrings = mutableListOf<String>()
val listOfEditedNumbers = mutableListOf<Int>()
allStrings.forEach {
    try {
        val toInt = it.toInt()
        listOfEditedNumbers.add(toInt)
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception){
        onlyStrings.add(it)
    }
}
val allNumbers = onlyNumbers.toList() + listOfEditedNumbers
val finalSortedNumberList = allNumbers.sorted()
val finalNumbersList = mutableListOf<Any>()
finalSortedNumberList.forEach {
    if (it in onlyNumbers) finalNumbersList.add(it)
    if (allStrings.contains(it.toString())) finalNumbersList.add(it.toString())
}
val finalTotalList = finalNumbersList + onlyStrings.sorted()
```

Comment: You've got a bug here - try it with an `Int` and a `String` version of the same number, you'll end up with four of them (two of each type). It's because that number will be present in `onlyNumbers` *and* `allStrings`, so for both instances of that number you add an `Int` version and a `String` version to your final list. Really you need the approach gidds used, where you keep the original objects and you only convert them when you're doing a comparison (in the sort function). That way you don't need to convert them back, and have to try and keep track of what was what